# Plot a function with an integer variable in Wolfram Alpha

Tags: wolframalpha

I'd like to plot the following function in Wolfram Alpha (n is a positive integer variable):

```
f = n * (2^(-n) - 1)
```

In Matlab the corresponding function is `stem`

How can I specify that n is a positive integer variable?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use discrete plot:

```
discrete plot f = n * (2^(-n) - 1) for 0 < n <= 10
```

Answer (score -1):

You can append a `plot` keyword at the beginning of your function. So, in your case, it would be something like this

```
plot f = n * (2^(-n) - 1) with n > 0
```

which will give the following result

[image]

Comment: Hello @FrancescoGimignano, thank you for your reply. I'm looking for a way to plot discete domain.

Comment: Check the edit, if I understand correctly you want something like this

Comment: Hi @FrancescoGimignano, the plot i'm looking for is like "stem" in Matlab, it's a series of stems.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't in the question. In that case I don't know if wolfram supports such operation :/